# Why is the table view not coming?

Tags: sql, oracle

**I am new to Oracle**. The [Oracle live SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database#Testing) shorthand gave ready-made code on the departments and employees model.

I don't understand why the code is not viewing any table although I wrote a select statement. I don't understand the execution protocol.

[link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:15703046042553::NO:93::&success_msg=MiBkYXRhYmFzZSBvYmplY3RzIGhhdmUgYmVlbiBkcm9wcGVkLiAgU2Vzc2lvbiBo.,aXN0b3J5IGhhcyBiZWVuIHJlbW92ZWQuIE5MUyBzZXR0aW5ncyByZXNldC4~%2F0v4EwtEsimRRLN7SydPg1vWmBH-mirK5DdGOYPR2AapaPAtuNFZWivY7uV8CaVlBt8MxMQjdgbZC0kOs-j9PQA)

```
create table departments (

    name                           varchar2(255) not null,
    location                       varchar2(4000),
    country                        varchar2(4000)
)
;

create table employees (
    department_id                  number
                                   constraint employees_department_id_fk
                                   references departments on delete cascade,
    name                           varchar2(50) not null,
    email                          varchar2(255),
    cost_center                    number,
    date_hired                     date,
    job                            varchar2(255)
)
;


insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Security',
    'Tanquecitos',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Travel',
    'Sugarloaf',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Office of the CEO',
    'Dale City',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Security',
    'Grosvenor',
    'United States'
);

commit;
-- load data

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Gricelda Luebbers',
    'gricelda.luebbers@aaab.com',
    20,
    sysdate - 94,
    'Systems Designer'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Dean Bollich',
    'dean.bollich@aaac.com',
    11,
    sysdate - 74,
    'Legal Assistant'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Milo Manoni',
    'milo.manoni@aaad.com',
    21,
    sysdate - 68,
    'Systems Designer'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Laurice Karl',
    'laurice.karl@aaae.com',
    78,
    sysdate - 73,
    'Programmer'
);

select
    departments.name                                   department_name,
    departments.location                               location,
    departments.country                                country,
    employees.name                                     employee_name,
    employees.email                                    email,
    employees.cost_center                              cost_center,
    employees.date_hired                               date_hired,
    employees.job                                      job
from
    departments,
    employees;
```

This is the output they are showing after running:

```
Table created.

ORA-02268: referenced table does not have a primary key

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

1 row(s) inserted.

Statement processed.

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: The problem lies in your code and is nothing to do with Oracle Live SQL. You would get the same error running the script in any other environment.

Comment: if i write (select * from departments) at the end of the code then the code is giving the output   NAME LOCATION COUNTRY
 Internal Systems Tanquecitos United States
  Logistics          Sugarloaf United States
  Security                Dale City          United States
Infrastructure Services Grosvenor United States

Answer (score 3):

Your table `departments` does not have a primary key, so the constraint in table `employees` produces an error, and the table `employees` is not created.

You should refactor your SQL code, adding a proper primary key to the table involved and manage the insert value properly:

```
create table departments (
id                             numeric(10) not null
name                           varchar2(255) not null,
location                       varchar2(4000),
country                        varchar2(4000),
CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;
```

Comment: If i modify the actual code at the create departments table with the soln that u have given (id numeric)  then the output that comes is  **ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SQL_CYRMIIYZHFMRUDVUJRGFLYABZ"."DEPARTMENTS"."ID") ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721


Statement processed.

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SQL_CYRMIIYZHFMRUDVUJRGFLYABZ.EMPLOYEES_DEPARTMENT_ID_FK) violated - parent key not found ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721**

Comment: you should refactor  all the code  ..  my answer is just an answer  related  to the fact your code  don't create  the table  you need ... but once you have created the table you must check that all you code is coherent

Comment: @SaumyojitDas - once you have added a primary key column to a table you need to amend your INSERT statements to populate that column (unless you're on 12c in which case you can choose to use an IDENTITY column).

Comment: [link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:14816042400601::NO:93::&success_msg=MCBkYXRhYmFzZSBvYmplY3RzIGhhdmUgYmVlbiBkcm9wcGVkLiAgU2Vzc2lvbiBo.,aXN0b3J5IGhhcyBiZWVuIHJlbW92ZWQuIE5MUyBzZXR0aW5ncyByZXNldC4~%2F2ZBzR3sqqwVXPeCkuNtJY5o-bXiBmMHzpas0br5NQ_K5nBap2gCwt8EWif-uY0_CTQ233xJ6abzPj3bq-OMpIg) here is the link see the modified code and new output

Comment: your link require login and password ..  .. i can't register on all support sites .. rather publish your example as text

Comment: then your error is resolved ... SO is not a coding service .. but a question answer  site  ... and your original question was about  "Why the table view is not coming ?"  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ...   so instead of use comment to ask a new question, you should post a new question specifically asking for your new problem with an example of the code you are using, your current result and the desired resolved

Comment: @scaisEdge  check in the [link](https://saumyojitdas.github.io/) . The output of the code that i have written is exacly not coming as i wanted. in the output table there is repetiton of rows after the first 4 rows.

Comment: how this is related to the error  "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"  ... ?????